# Making rails button_to link to a path with a parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to set up a button that goes to a path but I cannot figure out what to set the path to. Currently I have it set up like this:

`= button_to "buy" , product_card_path, :method => "get"`

but I get an error.

```
No route matches {:action=>"card", :controller=>"products"}
```

This is the path in the rake routes:

```
product_card GET   /products/:product_id/card(.:format)    products#card
```

How do I make a button_to go to a path that requires a parameter?

Comment: Post the relevant part of your `routes.rb`. It looks like you're most likely missing the :product_id. You could try `product_card_path(:product_id => @product.id)` or whatever is the instance of your product.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
= button_to "buy" , product_card_path(your_product_instance), method: :get
```

Not sure whether or not the `method: :get` is necessary here.

Comment: hmnn but what should i put in (your_product_instance)

Comment: Well, your product instance :) Do you have a `@product` available ? or Maybe a `product` ? If not, can you set it on your controller's action ? Like `@product = Product.new` maybe ? I can't answer without seeing more code.

Comment: = button_to "buy" , product_card_path(params[:id]), :method => "get"  worked flawlessly

Comment: ok yes, you can pass an ID too, however make sure this is a product id.